# OceanWP settings are missing from Add New Post

Tags: plugins, author, options

When logged in as Author, the screen options do not include [OceanWP](https://oceanwp.org/) settings. If logged in as Administrator, the options do include OceanWP settings.

The Author needs these settings to remove such things as breadcrumbs, comments, etc. from a certain kinds of posts.

Any help or direction greatly appreciated.
Theme: [OceanWP](https://oceanwp.org/) + [Ocean Extra](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ocean-extra/).

Elementor is installed but is not used for posts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can hook into the `ocean_main_metabox_capabilities` filter:

It is defined in `/plugins/ocean-extra/includes/metabox/metabox.php`:

```php
$capabilities = apply_filters( 'ocean_main_metaboxes_capabilities', 'manage_options' );
```

In your child theme or a custom plugin, try the following (for example, in `/themes/mytheme/functions.php`:

```php
add_filter( 'ocean_main_metaboxes_capabilities', 'my_custom_metabox_role' );

/**
 * Change the default role used to display the Ocean Extra metabox.
 * 
 * @param string $role The role to use, defaults to 'manage_options' (Administrator).
 * @return string
 */
function my_custom_metabox_role( $role ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) {
        return $role;
    }

    return 'publish_posts';
}
```